# Enabling Lightning app builder

Tags: lightning-apps

I would like to know how to enable the lightning app builder in my developer edition.

Thanks in advance.
Best regards

Comment: The Lightning App Builder will be GA with Summer 15 
http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_mobile_salesforce1_newfeat_appbuilder.htm

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Go to your name in top right.
> 2. Select setup from drop down.
> 3. In search text type "Lightning Components".
> 4. Click on the link and enable it.
> 5. For development, you can open developer console -> click file -> New -> Lightning Application

Hope this my help.

Comment: Lightning Applications are not the same as Lightning App Builder